# How to sort the values based upon aggregate data in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
PUT my-data-stream/_bulk
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T18:25:42","search_term":"hello", "counter": 10}
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T18:25:42","search_term":"bye", "counter": 5}
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T17:25:42","search_term":"hello", "counter": 9}
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T17:25:42","search_term":"bye", "counter": 7}
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T16:25:42","search_term":"hello", "counter": 5}
{"create":{}}
{"timestamp":"2022-05-06T16:25:42","search_term":"bye", "counter": 2}
```

Given the data set above. I want to sort (DESC) the search terms by sum of the counters which are greater than a specific timestamp.

For example: For timestamp greater than `2022-05-06T16:35:42` (which are top 4 records). Result should be

```
 Hello, 19 (10 + 9)
 Bye, 12 (5 + 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Tldr;

You can order your data using `order` in you aggregation.

As per the [documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

> In this case, the buckets are ordered by the actual term values, such as lexicographic order for keywords or numerically for numbers. This sorting is safe in both ascending and descending directions, and produces accurate results.

## Solution

```json
GET /74006495/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2022-05-06T16:35:42"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "search_terms": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "search_term.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": { "count": "desc" } // <- Here is the order by count agg
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "counter"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a filter by date and then aggs the results.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2022-05-06T16:35:42"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "search_by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "calendar_interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "search_term": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "search_term.keyword",
            "size": 10
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_counter": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "counter"
              }
            },
            "counter_bucket_sort": {
              "bucket_sort": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "total_counter": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "size": 3
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "search_by_day": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key_as_string": "2022-05-06T00:00:00.000Z",
          "key": 1651795200000,
          "doc_count": 4,
          "search_term": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "hello",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "total_counter": {
                  "value": 19
                }
              },
              {
                "key": "bye",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "total_counter": {
                  "value": 12
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to sort by sum of counters.